Replication pdns master slave
I am configuring a master slave dns in version 4.9. I have a small problem with my zones not replicating
master config
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-user=xxxxxxx
gmysql-password=xxxxxxxxxx
gmysql-dbname=xxxxxxx
local-address=127.0.0.1,10.17.253.253
#local-port=5300
local-port=53
daemon=no
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
primary=yes
allow-axfr-ips=10.12.12.141
allow-notify-from=10.12.12.141
#api=yes
#api=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
dnsupdate=yes
allow-dnsupdate-from=127.0.0.0/8
default-ttl=60
log-dns-queries=yes
log-dns-details=yes
loglevel=6
Konfig slave
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-user=xxx
gmysql-password=xxxxxxxxxxxx
gmysql-dbname=xxx
local-address=127.0.0.1,10.12.12.141
#local-port=5300
local-port=53
daemon=no
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
allow-notify-from=10.17.253.253,149.156.12.221
Ustawienia dla serwera slave
autosecondary=yes
secondary=yes
secondary-do-renotify=yes
dnsupdate=no
#allow-dnsupdate-from=127.0.0.0/8
default-ttl=60
#logowanie
log-dns-details=yes
log-dns-queries=yes
loglevel=6
